# División de int entre Double no muestra decimales

Tags: c#

actualmente tengo un problema que me parece muy particular, resulta que al hacer un código declarando una variable de tipo "doble" o "int" en Visual Studio, y realizar en ella una sencilla división como por ejemplo:

```
int nEntero = 5;
Double decimal = nEntero /100;

Console.WriteLine(decimal);

// La idea es que imprima 0.05 como resultado
// Pero en cambio me muestra solo el numero entero, osea 0.
```

Resulta que al usarlo para sacar por ejemplo porcentajes, todo da 0, porque todo numero multiplicado por 0, es igual a 0.

Les muestro algo de prueba sobre la salida que hace Visual Studio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco si me pueden ayudar a solucionarlo. Quedo atento.

Comment: 100 no es tomado como `double` a menos que lo indiques usando un punto de separación decimal, como por ejemplo: `nEntero / 100.` o también: `nEntero / 100.0`. Prueba eso y comenta el resultado.

Comment: Saludos @MauricioContreras muy bueno tu comentario, efectivamente si funciona, por favor pongalo como respuesta para aceptarla como solucionada. Eso soluciona mi falla.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Sucede que el valor literal 100 cuando es analizado por el compilador de C# (y por muchos otros lenguajes) se asume como tipo entero. Por lo tanto la división representada por:

```
nEntero / 100
```

[será también de tipo entero](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#integer-division), con lo cual los decimales se descartan y se devuelve el valor correspondiente a la parte entera.

Luego, el tipo que aplicas sobre la variable se realiza efectivamente pero sobre el valor del resultado de la división, el cual ya no tiene los decimales, produciéndose como salida simplemente un `0.0` (cuando `nEntero` es menor que `100`)

Por otro lado, el uso de la palabra reservada `decimal` para una variable no está permitido, no entiendo como tu programa siquiera compila.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una forma de solucionarlo es realizar una conversión del tipo de variable antes de realizar la división, tal como sugiere la [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394236/divisi%c3%b3n-de-int-entre-double-no-muestra-decimales/394238#394238), por ejemplo:

```
double descuento = (double)nEntero / 100;
```

O incluso:

```
double descuento = nEntero / (double)100;
```

Sin embargo, podemos evitar hacer el *cast* explícito escribiendo el valor 100 de tal forma que el mismo sea reconocido como un tipo de punto flotante. Para ello debemos acompañarlo de un punto decimal seguido de un cero o 2 ceros (o de cualquier valor para la parte decimal que se requiera). Por ejemplo:

```
double descuento = nEntero / 100.0;
```

O tal vez:

```
double descuento = nEntero / 100.00;
```

De esta forma, C# realizará el *cast* (de forma implícita) del tipo entero, representado por `nEntero`, a punto flotante, para luego proceder a realizar la división en punto flotante.

De acuerdo a las necesidades de tu aplicación, puedes establecer el nivel de precisión esperado usando los tipos `float`, `decimal` o `double`. Por ejemplo:

```
float descuento = nEntero / 100.0f; // <- Precisión simple (4 bytes)
double descuento = nEntero / 100.0d; // <- Precisión doble (8 bytes)
decimal descuento = nEntero / 100.0m // <- Precisión decimal (16 bytes)
```

Por último, una [acotación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#floating-point-division):

> Si uno de los operandos es `decimal`, el otro operando no puede ser `float` ni `double`, ya que ni `float` ni `double` se convierte de forma implícita a `decimal`. Debe convertir explícitamente el operando `float` o `double` al tipo `decimal`.

En el caso de tu pregunta, no hace falta tal conversión explícita porque un tipo `integer` si que puede ser convertido implícitamente a `decimal`.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Gracias @MauricioContreras es una respuesta muy bien sustentada, y a modo de aclaración no te preocupes por la variable ``` decimal ``` usada en el ejemplo de la pregunta, no puse mi código real ya que los valores lo estoy almacenando en atributos de una clase, pero para no hacer extensa la pregunta con tanto código, entonces lo hice así, solo que no tuve en cuenta que "decimal" es palabra reservada. La imagen mostrada, es el resultado del código como tal por eso se muestra en ejecución.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta parsear el nEntero a float...

```
int nEntero = 5;
Double decimal = float.Parse(nEntero) /100;

Console.WriteLine(decimal);

// La idea es que imprima 0.05 como resultado
// Pero en cambio me muestra solo el numero entero, osea 0.
```

Espero te haya sido de utilidad

Comment: Saludos @CarlosDuarte, no ya lo habia intentado incluso parseando con Double, pero el resultado seguia siendo 0, incluso quise obligar al sistema a que me pusiera dos decimales con el ```Math.Round(variable,2)```  pero tampoco me funcionaba, Mauricio Contreras me dio la solucion. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.