# ¿Porque al hacer esta operacion no me regresa decimales?

Tags: c#

me ha surgido esta duda ¿Porque al realizar esta operacion no me regresa decimales, solo enteros?

```
int N = 10;
int NumeroDeA = 2;
int longitud = 3;
float x = (N * NumeroDeA) / longitud;
```

Me da como resultado 6 en vez de 6.666666

Comment: Cómo estás visualizando el valor de x? no es evidente...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [División de int entre Double no muestra decimales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394236/divisi%c3%b3n-de-int-entre-double-no-muestra-decimales)

Answer (score 1):

No te muestra decimales porque las operaciones entre enteros no devuelven decimales para que te devuelva decimales debes cambiar el tipo de dato de tus variables (N, NumeroDeA y longitud) de int a float, quedaría algo así.

```
float N = 10f;
float NumeroDeA = 2f;
float longitud = 3f;
float x = (N * NumeroDeA) / longitud;
```

Answer (score 1):

Si consultas el orden de los operadores en la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence) verás que la asignación `=` se encuentra al final.

Con ello te das cuenta de que primero se evalúa toda la expresión de la derecha. Una vez terminada la evaluación, si el valor es compatible con el tipo de la variable o hay conversiones posibles, se realizan y finalmente a la variable.

Solo habrá una única conversión al tipo de la variable, de ser necesaria, cuando se asigne el valor.

Mientras se evalúa la expresión sí pueden suceder otras conversiones. También sucederán solo de ser necesarias.

Lo típico es que sea necesaria una conversión cuando se encuentran variables, valores o literales de diferentes tipos. Por ejemplo, cuando operas un `int` con un `float`, sucede una conversión implícita.

Considera el siguiente caso:

```
 var operacion = 1.5f + 1
```

La operación entre `float` e `int` no está definida. Cómo sí hay una conversión implícita definida de `int` a `float`, se convierte el 1 en `float` y el compilador no genera errores.

Si intentas hacer:

```
int numero = 1.0f;
```

Obtendrás un error, porque solo hay conversión explícita y cuando esto sucede, necesitas indicar que quieres llevarla a cabo mediante el uso de un `(float)`.

Así que si quieres obtener un resultado con decimales, uno de los operandos debe ser de tipo `float`. Esto puedes lograrlo declarando las variables de dicho tipo como mostró @Picardia o hacer un casteo.